# Postgres parse json stored as string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a json column in in the following table (`my_table`) which I have json saved as string, for example:

| index | json_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "{\"alpha\": {\"beta\": \"gamma\"}}" |

I would like to query let's say beta from it.

Comment: Is the data type of the column `json/jsonb` or a string type?

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling around I finally managed to figure this out:

```sql
select ((json_col::JSONB)->>0)::JSONB
from my_table
```

This will first get the first element of the string which is json and then cast it to json.

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score -1):

You stored double serialized data.

Example:

```js
// js
const json1 = JSON.stringify({name:"John"});
console.log(json1); // Result: '{"name":"John"}'

const json2 = JSON.stringify(json1);
console.log(json2); // Result: '"{\\"name\\":\\"John\\"}"'
```

Answer: Don't store double serialized data